# HTML Language in Marketing Cloud Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

We use Content Builder with a custom HTML template (stated and saved as UTF-8) and several content blocks (all in UTF-8) which use AMPscript (lookup) to retrieve information out of Data Extension, which are populated by automated import jobs (which use UTF-8 CSV files).

Customers informed us that at some (not all) devices, umlaute in some parts of our emails look weird - surprisingly, not only the DE-based info (2), but also hard coded content blocks (1):

[image]

Additionally, when I look on an email to edit, it shows me the following setup: 
[image]

What can be the root cause for that? Which "corresponding drop down" are they talking about? I can't find any way to format the language of either the template, the content block, the Data Extensions or the email itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature called "Target Language" with the drop-down to different encoding in the screenshot above is a feature that used to be part of a paid package.  However, it seems to now be included with all editions (as part of our new pricing and packaging).  You can get this enabled by calling into support.

Comment: Yes - after 3 days waiting time and escalating it to tier 2 support, the feature is now enabled in our account.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the enconding going to "Go to" dropdown by the top right of the screen, then go to Properties

[image]

There is a combo to change the enconding:

[image]

Comment: Weird - I can't see this field anywhere. Any idea how to switch that on?

Comment: You mean 'Target Language'?

Comment: Try to open a case in 'Salesforce Help and Training' or speak with your Account Executive.

Comment: As above: Yes - after 3 days waiting time and escalating it to tier 2 support, the feature is now enabled in our account